# Why Isaac Gym failed to parse URDF when I try the demo after installation

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, python-3.8, urdf, nvidia-isaac

I have tried to install Isaac Gym on Ubunt 18.04 with nvidia 1060 and the 470 driver.
Everything is ok after I "sudo apt install libpython3.7" following the official index.html.
However I got error showing:" failed to load '../..assests/urdf/ball/urdf'" with the ending of "segmentation fault"
I checked the directory and found the corresponding urdf file, it is confusing why the Isaac Gym gets such an error

I have searched over the Google but gotten nothing like my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your questions looks like some typo in the path. I guess you probably need to change the path to something like the following:

```
../../assets/urdf/ball.urdf
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).